# Responsive Web Design and Auotorotations

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I've read [this article about responsive web deisgn](http://bit.ly/a8Y7gP) from Ethan Marcotte. It Seems to me that It doesn't handle well my iPad and iPhone rotations. In other words when I turn my iPad or iPhone in landscape mode the code of [the final example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html) appear to detect a wrong viewport width (larger). Where I'm wrong?

Instead If I'm right does someone knows what I need to add to fix It?

Comment: Can you show the code you used based on that article?

Comment: @Pekka I'm trying the example linked into the article itself (added url now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s actually a bug with Mobile Safari’s handling of the meta viewport value of "width=device-width". http://bit.ly/hNzScW
Thanks to the guys at [**filamentgroup**](http://www.filamentgroup.com/) and Ethan Marcotte for pointing that out.